# CASE or IF - how to create a formula field with several IF?

Tags: formula, if

Im a bit confused in creation formula to calculate field Source on Case. the task is :

On Case create formula to calculate the following:
For users with country US show Account Source if Account Industry is Banking, if it is not Banking, show message: X
For users with country UA show Account Source if it is Web, otherwise, show message: Y
For users with country FR show Account Source if Account industry is Construction or Engineering, otherwise leave field empty

```
CASE(
    $User.Country, 
    'UA', IF(ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry, "Banking"), TEXT(Account.AccountSource), "X"),
    'US', "Web", 
    "Y"
)
```

Also tried

```
IF(
    AND(
        $User.Country = "US",
        ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry,"Banking")
    ), 
    TEXT(Account.AccountSource),
    'X',
    IF(
        AND(
            $User.Country = "UA",
            ISPICKVAL(Account.Source, "Web")
        ), 
        TEXT(Account.AccountSource),
        'Y',
        IF(
            AND(
                $User.Country = "FR", 
                OR(
                    ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry, "Construction"),
                    (ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry, "Engeneering"))
                )
            ), 
            TEXT(Account.AccountSource)," ")
        )
    )
```

In this case each of three condition works, but doesn't work togeather.
Please, consider it

Comment: Are you trying to achieve formula field calculation or validation rule?  and if it is formula calculation then specify the conditions and what is the value needs to be print. if it validation rule then specify the conditions when you want give an error message.

Comment: It should be a formula to calculate field Account Source based on conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I'm assuming that the formula field is on a standard object that has a lookup to `Account` (e.g. `Contact`, `Opportunity`, `Order`, etc):

```
CASE(
  $User.Country,
  'US', IF(ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry,'Banking'),TEXT(Account.Industry),'X'),  
  'UA', IF(ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry,'Web'),TEXT(Account.Industry),'Y'), 
  'FR', IF(OR(ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry,'Construction'),
              ISPICKVAL(Account.Industry,'Engineering')),
              TEXT(Account.Industry),NULL),  
   NULL
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also doesn't work Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'OR()'. Expected Boolean, received Text

Comment: oops - missed a paren

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You really made my day! Merry Christmas!

Comment: great!  as a service to the community use the check mark next to the answer to mark as `accepted`. This helps others when they encounter this question/answer